# Why the standard DH is not suﬃcient to ensure the security of the Diﬃe-Hellman key exchange?

Tags: diffie-hellman

I don't know mucho about Cryptography, I try to understand, It's for homework.

Why the standard DH is not suﬃcient to ensure the security of the Diﬃe-Hellman key exchange?

My answer was:

In the standard Diﬃe-Hellman key exchange protocol, both parties compute the secret value gαβ for two privately chosen values $\alpha$ (by Alice) and $\beta$ (by Bob). An eavesdropper can publicly see the pair ($g^{\alpha},g^{\beta}$). So, if checking whether, for some $g^{\gamma}$, it is the case that $\gamma = \alpha \beta$, were computationally easy —i.e., the DDH assumption fails—, then the eavesdropper would have found $g^{\gamma} = g^{\alpha\beta}$ without disclosing $\alpha$ nor $\beta$ explicitly, even if the DH assumption is true. This is why the CDH/DDH are the assumptions that really matter in the key exchange.

Comment: Presumably you're talking about non-authenticated D-H?  ("Schoolbook D-H").  Usually the first concern that comes to mind is the man-in-the-middle attack.

Comment: Are you referring to DH vs ECDH?

Comment: The teacher said it had nothing to do with authentication.

Comment: Did you mean to say: why the **DL** assumption is not enough? Your example is going in the right direction and would need to be modified to say that even if the **DL** is hard, if it was possible to compute $g^{xy}$ from $g^x, g^y$ then the key exchange would not be secure